# LoadUI and SoapUI and Rest API backend does not execute

Tags: rest, soapui, loadui

I am currently using LoadUI and SoapUI for Load Testing a REST API. However each time I ran either my functional tests from SoapUI or my Load Tests based on the SoapUI project the backend code does not execute.

I expected to see the service doing what it was supposed to however nothing happens?

Is this normal behavior for Soap and LoadUI? Are they simply just simulating Load rather than executing the code?

I hope anyone can help me get out of this foggy area where I am at. Also it is the first time I am testing Web services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what you are saying it seems that your services aren't called. Maybe you aren't using the endpoints for the server you want to test?

Comment: When you say "backend code", I am assuming you are referring to the WS server. Both SoapUI and LoadUI actually send messages to the server itself, there is no simulation ... unless you are using the mocking feature - you would know if you were. Something else must be going on. As @JoelJonsson suggested: maybe you are using the wrong endpoints. What do you see in the SoapUI logs?

Comment: All my requests seem to execute correctly in the Application according to logs, there were no errors and pointed to the correct endpoints.

Comment: I've just started evaluating the LoadUI to test REST API and I'm seeing the same thing. I'm trying to hit a public method, using the following setup http://imgur.com/HQGzTwU What am I doing wrong